# How do I make a chrome extension whose forms stay filled even after closing/opening the extension?

Tags: javascript, html

My chrome extension has forms in it. I want to make my extension such that when the form is filled by the user and the save button is pressed, the forms stay filled the next time the extension is closed and opened again.

Here is the code:

manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "DRIP",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "DRIP is an automation tool for purchasing limted items",
"permissions": ["storage", 
    "tabs",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/"
],

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",

"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
}
}
```

background.js: 
(No code, I just have it in the folder)

popup.js:

```
const profile = document.forms.profile
var fName = profile.elements.fName

document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", save)

function save() {
chrome.storage.local.set({"fName": fName.value}, function(){
  alert("saved" + fName.value)
});
}

  var fNameSaved = 
    chrome.storage.local.get("fName", function(data) {
    alert('Value currently is ' + document.getElementById("fName").value)
  });

  document.getElementById("fName").value = fNameSaved


//next step = keep form filled after opening/closing app
```

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>    
        <script language='javascript' src='popup.js' defer></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <form name="profile">
                <input id="fName" name="fName" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
                <input id="lName" name="lName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                <input id="save" name="save" type="button" value="Save">
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: this code should work to make the form auto-filled if value is stored in local storage

Comment: @FahadMahmood it doesn't. When I close and open my extension the form in cleared.

Answer (score 0):

try changing it like this

```
    chrome.storage.local.get("fName", function(data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty("fName")) {
      document.getElementById("fName").value = data.fName;
    }
  });
```

also check what are you getting in data it would be like data.value etc

Comment: After implementing your solution, the "First Name" field become "[object Object]. 
And after closing/opening the extension again, the form is empty.

Do you have any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: so data returns an object

Comment: can you check and see what is returned in console?  I have added console.log(data);